# WPF - How to run code immediately after a Window is hidden

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi, window

In my app I take a screenshot of the desktop. Right before that I hide my app's `Window`, so It will not cover part of the desktop:

```
MainWindow.Hide();  
TakeScreenShot();
```

The problem is that sometimes the Window does not get hidden fast enough, so I ended up taking a screenshot of it too. I have tried taking the screenshot from a `Window.IsVisibleChanged` event handler, but the result is the same.

Of course, I can use `Thread.Sleep` or similar, but I am looking for a better solution.

**Update**

I have just switched to Aero theme and enabled Desktop Composition, and now the situation is even worse. Now the window "fade out" instead of instantly hidden when calling `Window.Hide`. So now my app *always* take a screenshot of a fading window... I will try winapi with [`SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) and will post an update.

**Update 2**

1. `ShowWindow` and `SetWindowPos` give the same result as `Window.Hide` (`Window.Hide` uses `ShowWindow(HWND, SW_HIDE)` internally).
2. In order to disable the fade-out effect when hiding the window, I use [`DwmSetWindowAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969524(v=vs.85).aspx).

like this:

```
using System.Windows.Interop;  
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]  
private static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, ref int attrValue, int attrSize);

private const int DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED = 3;
```

and in the `Window.Loaded` event handler:

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) {

    IntPtr WinHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;

    int BOOL_TRUE = 1;

    int HR = DwmSetWindowAttribute(WinHandle, DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED, BOOL_TRUE, Marshal.SizeOf(BOOL_TRUE));

    if (HR != 0)
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(HR);
}
```

So beside the fade-out effect, the problem remain.

Comment: Have you tried simple [OnDeactivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.deactivated(v=vs.110).aspx)? or [OnStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.statechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) with filter checking `minimized` state?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: I have tried to take the screenshot from Window.Deactivated event handler. Result is the same. I didn't try from StateChanged, because I don't want to minimize the window.

Comment: @Bohoo can you tell me how you `TakeScreenShot` looks like?

Comment: Did you tried to change the visibility of your window to Window.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed? Try to do that apart with the Window.Deactivated event handler again.

Comment: @Gopichandar: I use System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen

Comment: @Ilan: I have tried that, same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with punting your window outside the area you are trying to copy(when a sub window restore issue was taken into account).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private DispatcherOperation _action;
    private int _width = 2000;
    private int _height = 1000;
    private double _top;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationCompleted += HooksOnOperationCompleted;
    }

    private void HooksOnOperationCompleted(object sender, DispatcherHookEventArgs dispatcherHookEventArgs)
    {
        if(dispatcherHookEventArgs.Operation != _action) return;
        _action.Task.ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, _width, _height);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            bmp.Save("help" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                Top = _top;
            }));
        });


    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _top = Top;
        _action = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
        {
            Top = 10000;
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Putting the window off screen works, but its a hack... I don't know what actually happen when I do this, and what are the consequences. Since it is a production code, I prefer not to use it. Also you can see my update to my question.

Comment: Ok @Bohoo. But I can't understand what do you mean by saying; "what  actually happen when I do this, and what are the consequences". By applying Top=Y_POSITION You just move the window to specific(Y_POSITION) position on the screen. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try minimizing the `Window` before hiding the `Window` and run it `Asynchronously` with least priority .  Something like this.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Minimize here before hiding. . 
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;  //this is the key
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action(() =>
        {                
            CaptureImage();
        }));            
    }

    private void CaptureImage()
    {
        System.Drawing.Rectangle bounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth, (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight);
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(System.Drawing.Point.Empty, System.Drawing.Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }
            bitmap.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I prefer not to minimize the window, because of the animation it involves. Using `DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle` by itself didn't help. You can see the an update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>{ 
   Thread.Sleep(2000);

   TakeScreenShot();
});
```